# Embedded Database into Jar File

Tags: java, jar, derby

For the past couple of days I have been trying to get my Derby database to be accessed in my jar file. Here is what my connection class looks like:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DBConnection
{
    public static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:EmployeeInfo";
    public static Connection dbConnector()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection successfull");
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is a screenshot of what my project explorer looks like: 
[image: Note that the database jar file is my apache derby database]

Everything works when I am in eclipse, my program runs as expected with my GUI updating the Database. But the minute I make my program a jar file it says it can't find my database EmployeeInfo (note: Database.jar is the EmployeeInfo database). One last thing, when I try the jar file out on a different machine it also states that it cannot find the database.

An explination on why this is going along with any fixes would be great!
-Thanks, 
Aaron :)

Comment: All .jar file entries should be considered read-only.  If you want to modify an entry, copy it to a temporary file and modify that file.

Comment: When you say temporary file, what does that mean exactly?

Comment: If you only need the modified database for a single run of your program, you can just copy the database from Class.getResourceAsStream to a file made with Files.createTempFile.  If you need the changes to the database to be permanent (so subsequent runs of your program can read them), pick a consistent location for the file, like System.getProperty("user.home").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i eventually found the fix :). I had to place the embedded derby database files into a folder along with the derby jars, and my jar file that contained my project and everything worked beautifully!